# Issue with NULL values using NOT IN

Tags: sql-server

I have a query where I'm trying to remove all records where if the combination of practice and entity only shows up once, and that one record has a status of Terminated or Withdrawn, then I want it removed.  If the practice/entity has more than one record, and at least one of those records is status of other than Terminated/Withdrawn, then I want to keep those other records.  I wrote a query that does this, which is shown below.

However, the issue I'm having is that the query is removing NULL records.  I understand that this is because of the Exists/NOT IN clauses, where NULL <> (Terminated, Withdrawn) evaluates to UNKNOWN.

I tried writing the query in the opposite way, using NOT EXISTS/IN, but that removed thousands of other records.  Does anyone know how to include the NULL values in this situation?

```
    declare @tab Table
    (practice  varchar(100),
    entity    varchar(100),
    assignedto varchar(100),
    statusname varchar(50)
     )
    insert into @tab values ('F&S', 'Sinai', 'AnnM', NULL);
    insert into @tab values ('F&S', 'Levin', 'AnnM', NULL);
    insert into @tab values ('F&S', 'Hopkins','AnnM', NULL);

    select *,
    ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by entity, statusname order by entity) as rn
    from @tab t1
    where exists(select *
                 from @tab t2
                 where t1.practice = t2.practice
                 and t1.entity= t2.entity
                 and t1.assignedto = t2.assignedto
                 and t2.statusname not in( 'Withdrawn', 'Terminated'));
```

Comment: dumbest way: `(t2.statusname not in( 'Withdrawn', 'Terminated') or t2.statusname IS NOT NULL)`

Comment: @LONG There is nothing dumbest there. Should be the correct way.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, haha, just be lazy using `ISNULL`, etc like the answer posted below xD, thank you

Comment: @LONG You should enclose it with `(... OR ...)` to avoid confusion. `WHERE` contains more than one condition :)

Comment: ISNULL, COALESCE will work, however they will not use indexes. you can do AND NOT (t2.statusname in( 'Withdrawn', 'Terminated'))

Comment: @lad2025, edited ;)

Comment: @LONG if the statusname will be 'Withdrawn' you will have TRUE. Most probably you meant  (not in ... OR t2.statusname IS NULL)

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev, thank you and @ lad2025, edited that :)

Comment: @LONG If you dont make that an answer I will. I think is better than `ISNULL`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza,  it depends on op's real case scenario, thumbs up for both if regardless of performance issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rather use `t2.statusname IS NULL`  so optimizer still can use any index.

```
select *,
       ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by entity, statusname order by entity) as rn
from @tab t1
where exists(select 1
             from @tab t2
             where t1.practice = t2.practice
               and t1.entity= t2.entity
               and t1.assignedto = t2.assignedto
               and (t2.statusname IS NULL OR
                    t2.statusname not in ('Withdrawn', 'Terminated')
                   )
            );
```

Comment: AND NOT (t2.statusname in ('Withdrawn', 'Terminated')) will be the shorter version of the same code

Comment: This seems to work, thanks!  A lot simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ISNULL` with dummy value:

```
select *,
ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by entity, statusname order by entity) as rn
from @tab t1
where exists(select *
             from @tab t2
             where t1.practice = t2.practice
             and t1.entity= t2.entity
             and t1.assignedto = t2.assignedto
             and ISNULL(t2.statusname, '@@@') 
                 not in( 'Withdrawn', 'Terminated'));
```

**[Rextester.com](http://rextester.com/GATA73099)**

Comment: `t2.statusname IS NOT NULL` is better. can use index

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza In general yes (**SARGable counts** :)). Still in OP's example there is table variable so it doesn't matter

Comment: *Don't* use ISNULL. `IS NOT NULL AND status name not in` can take advantage of any indexes. `ISNULL(...)` on the other hand will force a full table scan in order to calculate the result

Comment: A table variable can have primary keys and indexes as well

Comment: I'm not using a table variable.  I just created one here so people can test it.